# Right way to use multiple buttons in angular form

Tags: angular, angular-forms

i am building a from with [angular forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms) and it works well with 1 button. But when i want to have 2 buttons, it is hard to handle. 
I want to have 1 button `reset` and 1 button `submit`. `reset` must be placed before `submit`. Here is the template:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" [formGroup]="form">
    //inputs...
    <button type="submit" (click)="reset($event)">reset</button>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

When i press `enter` in one input, the `form` fire both `submit()` and   `reset($event)` function. It is the same when i click on `reset` button. My expectation is:

- When press `enter` or click `submit` button, the form only fire `submit()` function
- When click `reset` button the form only fire `reset()` function

I can find a walk around is adding a hidden button before `reset`    button and call `event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault()` in    `reset()` function. But it is ugly. Is there a clean way to do it? Any    help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: just remove `type="submit"` from the reset button.....

Comment: @Claies: I tried it but same behaviour

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You have to set your reset button's `type` to `button`, not `submit`. You have to explicitly set it because default value of attribute `type` is `submit`:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submit()" [formGroup]="form">
    //inputs...
    <button type="button" (click)="reset($event)">reset</button>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: With Angular Material I like to use it like this: `<button mat-raised-button type="submit" color="primary">submit</button>`

Comment: Had similar issue. I had two buttons - first without type defined and second with `type="submit"`. The problem was that on enter in the form first button was clicked instead of submit button. Once I added `type=button` to the firs button, then the second button is raised on enter key. And everything works as desired. Thanks.